# orbeon insert in repeat

Tags: xforms, orbeon

I am having trouble inserting row with xbl components at a particular position. It works if I insert row at the end but if I try to insert row in the middle then xbl components init method is not called.

Here is the xhtml.

```
<xhtml:head>
    <xforms:model id="main" 
                  xxforms:session-heartbeat="true"
                  xxforms:show-error-dialog="false" 
                  xxforms:external-events="submit-save submit-preview submit-cancel">

        <xforms:instance id="instance">
            <root>
                <repeat>
                    <item>
                        <title/>
                    </item>
                </repeat>           
            </root>
        </xforms:instance>

        <xforms:instance id="proto-property">
            <item>
                <title/>
            </item>
        </xforms:instance>

        <xforms:bind nodeset="instance('instance')">
            <xforms:bind
                nodeset="repeat/item/title"
                required="true()" />
        </xforms:bind>

    </xforms:model>
    <xbl:xbl xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
     xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude"
     xmlns:xxforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
     xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
     xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
     xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
     xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl"
     xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xbl:script src="/apps/xforms-sandbox/samples/input-counted.js" />

    <xbl:binding id="fr-input-counted" element="fr|input-counted">
        <xbl:template xxbl:transform="oxf:unsafe-xslt">
            <xsl:transform version="2.0">
                <xsl:import href="oxf:/oxf/xslt/utils/xbl.xsl" />
                <xsl:template match="/*">
                    <xforms:group xbl:attr="model context ref bind" xxbl:scope="outer">

                        <xbl:content includes="xforms|label" />                             

                        <xsl:copy-of select="xxbl:parameter(., 'max')" />

                        <xxforms:script ev:event="xforms-enabled" ev:target="#observer">
                            YAHOO.xbl.fr.InputCounted.instance(this).initialize();
                        </xxforms:script>

                        <xforms:group xxbl:scope="inner">
                            <xxforms:variable name="binding" as="node()?">
                                <xxforms:sequence select="." xxbl:scope="outer"/>
                            </xxforms:variable>
                            <xforms:input id="input-counted" class="fr-input-counted" ref="$binding" incremental="true" />
                            <label class="counter-label"></label>
                        </xforms:group>
                    </xforms:group>
                </xsl:template>
            </xsl:transform>
        </xbl:template>
    </xbl:binding>

</xbl:xbl>

</xhtml:head>

<xhtml:body class="body">

    <div>
        <xforms:trigger appearance="full">
            <xforms:label>
              Add Another  
            </xforms:label>
            <xforms:insert ev:event="DOMActivate" at="1"
            nodeset="repeat/item"/>
        </xforms:trigger>
    </div>

    <xforms:repeat nodeset="repeat/item">
        <div>
            <fr:input-counted ref="title" max="10">
                <xforms:label>Node Selector </xforms:label>
            </fr:input-counted>
        </div>
    </xforms:repeat>
</xhtml:body>
```

Try to click on Add Another multiple times and you will see that it is not populating the size next to input box.

You can download the required js file from the following URL. (http://orbeon-forms-ops-users.24843.n4.nabble.com/Error-in-repeat-for-controls-having-relevant-td2331649.html#a2533819). It is the same error but made it simple by removing the relevant.

I am using Orbeon 3.8 and xforms.js line 3798 has the following code. If I have "at" attribute in insert it never goes inside. This is because I am trying to insert a row where a row was previously initialized.

```
                    if (! this.initialized) {
                        originalInit.call(this);
                        this.initialized = true;
                    }
```

Is this is a bug?

Thank You
Binesh Gummadi

Comment: Could you create a single file that contains the XHTML+XBL+JS, so we can more easily reproduce this, and update your example? I tried doing that, but got to the point where `YAHOO.xbl.fr.InputCounted.instance(this).initialize()` is called, and `initialize()` isn't defined anywhere in your code. See: http://pastie.org/1272744

Comment: Thanks for answering Alex. My bad! Please look at this http://pastie.org/1272963 which has the right javascript

Right now insert has at="1" so error will happen from 3rd iteration. If you change it to 2 then you can see the error from 4th iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the full example; that really helps. I've been able to run this, and see my response (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090978/orbeon-insert-in-repeat/4136986#4136986).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

First, make sure that the method used to initialize your object is called `init()` (not `initialize()`). This because the plumbing that gets injected when you call `ORBEON.xforms.XBL.declareClass()` makes sure that every time you call `instance()`, if an instance for the current component can't be found, one is created, and `init()` is being called on that object. It also ensure that `init()` is called just once.

Second, add `xxforms-iteration-moved` in addition to `xforms-enabled` to the events that trigger the XBL object to be initialized:

```
<xxforms:script ev:event="xforms-enabled xxforms-iteration-moved" ev:target="#observer">
    YAHOO.xbl.fr.InputCounted.instance(this).init();
</xxforms:script>
```

With those two changes, from what I can see, the component seems to get properly initialized (I am getting the 0/10 on each line after the text field).

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/768034

Here is the simplified version of the same error. When control becomes relevant after making it irrelevant init method is not called which goes back to my previous observation(xforms.js line 3798).

Steps to reproduce

1. Observe two alerts upon page load
2. Uncheck the check box
3. Check the check box (observe only one alert. "initialized" alert is not displayed)

Is this the right behavior?

Comment: I posted an answer as another answer instead of updating my earlier answer, as this looks like another (related) question (where you don't have a repeat here.

Answer (score 0):

(This is an answer to a follow-up [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090978/orbeon-insert-in-repeat/4616780#4616780) posted as an answer on this page. Hem.)

Yes, this is the intended behavior, and I understand how this can be confusion. The idea of the `init()` method is to initialize your JavaScript object and do some initialization to the DOM. If you get an instance of your object with `instance()`, then this method will be called automatically for you before any other method is called on your object.

This explains why you don't see `init()` called when your component becomes enabled again. What you want to do here is split the code your in `init()` into:

- The part that really initializes the component — which you keep in `init()`.
- The part that changes the appearance of your component so it shows as enabled — which you put in a new method `enabled()`.

Then you write:

```
<xxforms:script ev:event="xforms-enabled">
    YAHOO.xbl.fr.InputCounted.instance(this).enabled();
</xxforms:script>
```

Note that you don't need to call `init()` explicitly; this will be done for you before any other method is called. Something similar is done in code for the [fr:button](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources-packaged/xbl/orbeon/button/button.xbl#L70).